# How to calculate translation and rotation of pulley

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics

This is **not** a homework question because I do not want help with solving my homework. I would rather want an explanation of what the logic behind this is and how it works.

*Background information*
[image]

*My problem*

I know that the pulley should lower at some speed and rotate if $V_A \neq V_B$? That I can understand using intuition I think. However, I do not understand the relation between the speed of the cables and the rotation/speed of pulley. What is the "best" way to approach this kind of problem? If $V_A=V_B$ then there is no rotation? But if the speed if different, how will the relationship between cable speed and rotation/pulley speed relate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start building your intuition from special cases (like you have done for $v_A = v_B$). The next special case to consider is that only one of the side pulleys is giving rope, i.e. let's say $v_B = 0$. Then it is easy to see that the main pulley should be descending at $0.5v_A$. How about the rotation? The main pulley and the pulley A have to pass the same amount of arc in a time unit, because we assume the rope does not stretch. Then the rope length passed from pulley A is $s = \alpha_A r_A$, where $\alpha_A$ is the angle the pulley has turned, and similarly for the main pulley $s = \alpha_C r_C$. Since these are equal we get $\alpha_C = \frac{r_A}{r_C}\alpha_A$, or if we want it just as a function of the rope length $\alpha_C = \frac{s}{r_C}$, or the speed $\omega_C = \frac{v_A}{r_C}$.

Now what happens if $v_A \neq v_B$ and neither is zero? For the height, the main thing to notice is that it does not matter from which pulley the rope is given, the main pulley makes sure that there are same lengths of rope on both sides. One way to think this is that both pulleys feed rope independently, but their effects are only half of what they feed, i.e. $v_C = 0.5(v_A + v_B)$. The angle of the middle pulley can be calculated with the same mind set, the main difference being that the pulleys A and B now rotate the main pulley to different directions. Using the results in first paragraph, we then get $\omega_C = \frac{v_A}{r_C} - \frac{v_B}{r_C}$.

Answer (score 0):

How about imagining a painted marker on each cable which is just above the pulley.  The marker for each cable will move with the speed of the respective cable.  The only thing that matters as far as the main pulley rotation is the difference in height between those two markers etc.  I hope this helps.